# How to select an xmltree recursive?

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle10g

I have given the following table. This table contains xml tag and value and optionally the reference to the parent tag.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE XML_TAG_VAL
(
  OBJ_ID     NUMBER, -- unique for one whole xml document
  ID         NUMBER, -- unique for every tag
  TAG        VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE), -- tags name
  VAL        CLOB, -- tags value
  LVL        NUMBER, -- depth of the tag
  ATTR_ID    NUMBER, -- foreign key to tag_attr table (do this later)
  PARENT_ID  NUMBER -- id of parent tag (xml_tag_val.id)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
NOCACHE;
```

Lets insert some very simple test-data into this table ...

```
insert into xml_tag_val values(1,1,'a',null,1,null,null);
insert into xml_tag_val values(1,2,'b','b-value',2,null,1);
insert into xml_tag_val values(1,3,'b','b-value 2',2,null,1);
```

What I have to do now is to generate a XML for a given client interface. So the result should be:

```
<a>
 <b>b-value</b>
 <b>b-value 2</b>
</a>
```

So for this specific case a hand made sql using xmlelement will not be an issue. But how do I select the xml tree without knowing how deep the path will go? What I know is just that every children points to its parent.

**EDIT 1:**
I have found out there is a way to use recursive queries to build XML, I have the following query:

```
declare
  l_qry_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
  l_result clob;
  l_obj_id number := 1;
begin
  l_qry_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy('
    select level,xmlelement(tag, val) 
       from oranetted_plugin.xml_tag_val 
         where obj_id = ' || l_obj_id || '
         start with parent_id is null 
           connect by parent_id = prior id'
  );
  l_result:=dbms_xmlgen.getxml(l_qry_ctx);

  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);           
end;
/
```

The Problem is that the tags name can not be feed from the sqls result. Instead of "a" or "b" the tag is shown as "tag".

```
<TAG>
  <TAG>b-value</TAG>
  <TAG>b-value 2</TAG>
</TAG>
```

Any ideas to get around this?

Comment: Do you have list of possible tag names?

Comment: @Marcin Wroblewski: Not finally, but I can generate one dynamically with `select distinct tag from xml_tag_val where obj_id=1`

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is ugly but probably gives the desired result

```
declare
   l_qry_ctx    dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
   l_result     clob;
   l_expression varchar2(32767);
   l_obj_id     number := 1;
begin
   for r in (select distinct tag from xml_tag_val) loop
      l_expression := l_expression || ' when ''' || r.tag ||
                      ''' then xmlelement(' || r.tag || ',val)';
   end loop;
   l_expression := 'case tag ' || l_expression || ' end';
   l_qry_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy('
    select level,' ||
                                                    l_expression || '
       from xml_tag_val 
         where obj_id = ' ||
                                                    l_obj_id || '
         start with parent_id is null 
           connect by parent_id = prior id');
   l_result := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(l_qry_ctx);

   dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
/
```

... however you have to remember about CASE expression limitation.

Comment: hmm ... nice one. The maximum number of arguments in a CASE expression is 255. I think this will be enough to be on the save side I have to count and raise an application error in case of >255

Answer (score 0):

Marcin led me into the right direction, thanks!

If someone have a similar issue you can use a function instead of building a big case statement. So this is my final working solution:

```
  create or replace
  function calc_xml_element(
     i_tag varchar2
    ,i_val clob
    ,i_attr_id number := null
  ) return xmltype
  is
    l_res      xmltype;
    l_sql      varchar2(4000);
    l_attr_sql varchar2(4000) := 'XMLATTRIBUTES(';
  begin
    if i_attr_id is not null then
      for tupl in 
        (select * from xml_tag_attr where id = i_attr_id)
      loop
        l_attr_sql := l_attr_sql || '''' || substr(tupl.attr_val,1,255) || ''' as "' || tupl.attr || '",';  
      end loop; 

      l_attr_sql := rtrim(l_attr_sql,',') || ')';
      l_sql := 'begin select xmlelement("' || i_tag || '",' || l_attr_sql || ',:val) into :a from dual; end;';
    else
      l_sql := 'begin select xmlelement("' || i_tag || '",:val) into :a from dual; end;';
    end if;

    execute immediate l_sql
      using in i_val, in out l_res; 

    return l_res;

    exception when others then
      raise_application_error(-20000,'Calc XML failed ' || l_sql, true);
  end calc_xml_element;
/
```

Now you can do:

```
insert into oranetted_plugin.xml_tag_val values(1,1,'a',null,1,null,null);
insert into oranetted_plugin.xml_tag_val values(1,2,'b','b-value',2,null,1);
insert into oranetted_plugin.xml_tag_val values(1,3,'b','b-value 2',null,1,1);

declare
   l_qry_ctx    dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
   l_result     clob;
   l_obj_id     number := 1;
begin    
   l_qry_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy('
    select level, oranetted_plugin.calc_xml_element(tag,val,attr_id) ' ||
       'from oranetted_plugin.xml_tag_val 
         where obj_id = ' || l_obj_id || '
         start with parent_id is null 
           connect by parent_id = prior id');

   l_result := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(l_qry_ctx);
   dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
/
```